# How to change Edit Menu in UICollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uicollectionview

I use UICollectionView to make a small app.
I just want to change Edit Menu when tap "longPress" but can not.

Ex. Change "Cut" to "Delete".

---

I implement my ActionSheet like the code below.
But that's not I want because I must implement ActionSheetDelegate outside the scope of UICollectionView.

I want to implement ActionSheet inside `performAction` method for easy to control.
Any suggestion? Thank you!

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(QSCollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    QSCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIActionSheet *deleteButton = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remove: %@",[collectionView.collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [deleteButton showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 57, 57, 20) inView:cell animated:NO];
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)collectionView:(QSCollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender{
    return YES;
}
-(void)collectionView:(QSCollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender{
}
//ActionSheet
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"Delete");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement your own `UIActionSheet` class and show that when `longPress` action is occurred.

Here is the [protocol document for UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006799) and the [UIActionSheet class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: What if I would like it to be like a menu and not an action sheet?